# About the second homotopy group of a Lie group

Tags: lie-groups, homotopy-theory

I have heard that the second homotopy group of some Lie groups is trivial, but I am confused about the conditions under which this is true. In some references there are no conditions at all, in some others that it should be compact, while others assume that it should be connected as well. So, which is the minimum set of requirements under which the second fundamental group of a Lie group is trivial?

Any references that clarify this matter would be appriciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's true. Connectedness doesn't matter, for $\pi_2$ is computed wrt a basepoint, and any part of the group not in the same component as the basepoint will have no effect.

Compactness makes it easier to prove, I believe. But see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/8957/homotopy-groups-of-lie-groups

which uses the (big) fact that a Lie group deformation retracts onto something compact, which is the only missing step.

Comment: Thank's, but I have already seen this post and in the second paragraph it says "Every (connected) Lie group...". However, since I don't quite uderstand the proof, I am not sure whether connectedness is relevant.

Comment: I've told you why connectedness doesn't matter to the final result: $\pi_2(G)$ is the same as $\pi_2(H)$, where $H$ is the connected component of the identity (which is a Lie subgroup). In short: this shows that if the theorem is true for connected groups, then it's true for all groups. And then that quoted proof shows it's true for connected ones.

Comment: The point of connectedness in the proof is to reduce to the compact case.  For example, it is not true that $\mathbb{Z}$ deformation retracts onto it's only compact subgroup $\{0\}$.  The point of reducing to the compact case is to use a bi-invariant metric, so that geodesics are easy to understand.  But, as John says, connnectedness is irrelevant:  In a Lie group, all components are diffeomorphic.  In fact, if $g \in G$, then left multiplication by $g$, $L_g:G\rightarrow G$ restricts to a diffeomorphism between the identity component of $G$ and whatever component $g$ is in.