# Homotopy groups $\pi_d(G)$ of exceptional Lie groups $G$ for Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$

Tags: algebraic-topology, differential-topology, lie-groups, lie-algebras, homotopy-theory

> Homotopy groups of exceptional Lie groups for Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$

It is commonly say the Lie groups of given exceptional Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}_{2}$, ${\mathfrak {f}}_{4}$,${\mathfrak {e}}_{6}$,
${\mathfrak {e}}_{7}$, ${\mathfrak {e}}_{8}$ are $G_2$, $F_4$, $E_6$, $E_7$, $E_8$. What the homotopy groups  $$\pi_d(G)$$ of these Lie groups $G$ for lower dimensions say $d=0,1,2,3,4,5$?

Partial answers are welcome!!! For example, if you know $d=1$, that can count as one answer; if you know $d=2$, that can count as another one answer.

Note that: In a previous question, I also asked whether there are more and different Lie groups of the same exceptional Lie algebra? for $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exceptional_Lie_algebra and [Different Lie groups of the same exceptional Lie algebra? for $\mathfrak{g_2,f_4,e_6,e_7,e_8}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3799800/141334)

Comment: I'm gonna do the easy thing and point out $\pi_2$ of all of these is trivial since it is trivial for any lie group. Another easy thing one can say is that $\pi_1$ is $H_1$ since the fundamental group is abelian. I'm not familiar with these groups but the take away should be that $d=1,2,3$ should be easy since the first homology is probably known, and the 3rd homology of the universal cover should also be computable.

Comment: [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2070960/about-the-second-homotopy-group-of-a-lie-group) about $\pi_2$ of a Lie group.

Comment: Crossposted to MO: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/369887/